# Handling exceptions on cucumber scenarios

Tags: exception, cucumber

I'm suffering from selenium's awkward behavior for alert boxes [described here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3600). Until this is resolved I need to rescue from `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError`.

This is easily done when I've created the step where the exception originates: I plop in a rescue block and it works fine.

But what if the step is an existing one that I want to rescue from, in this case, checking a checkbox? I can't do anything at this level--can I?--so I thought adding a tag to the scenario and an around hook like the following would work, but it doesn't:

```
Around('@handle_alert_boxes') do |scenario, block| do
  begin
    block.call
  rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError
    puts "It's OK!"
  end
end
```

I also tried cucumber's `@allow-rescue` tag, but it appears this only works when handling exceptions *external* to cucumber (like Rails) but not *internal* (like its driver--selenium).

Is there a way to handle this without creating a new step with a rescue block? That doesn't feel right and it will pollute my cucumber's vernacular.

Comment: Hi! Any news on solving this problem?

Comment: What happens if you rescue Error ? Just to be sure you are not trying to rescue the wrong type or error.