# Rescuing Selenium WebDriver exceptions inside cucumber Around statement

Tags: ruby, exception, cucumber, selenium-webdriver

I'm using the ruby selenium webdriver with cucumber to run multiple browser tests. I have several steps where exceptions could be raised, and don't want to put a begin/rescue block around every step. I found cucumber's Around hook which should allow me to call all of my steps in one big block, and put a begin/rescue block around that. Unfortunately, when a selenium exception is raised, the block never receives the exception. I'm theorizing that cucumber, for whatever reason, has it's own begin/rescue block which gets triggered before mine. For rails there's a tag called @allow-resue that lets the exception pass, unfortunately this won't work for Selenium. Does anyone know a work-around?

Comment: My question is very similar to this one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787032/handling-exceptions-on-cucumber-scenarios?rq=1

Comment: But it seems that no one was able to help with this one, and that was about a year ago

Answer (score 0):

Around hook won't help.  At all.  You need only look at 'around_hook.rb' 'execute' method definition:

```
def execute(*args, &continue)
  @timer.start
  @block.call(continue)
  Result::Unknown.new # Around hook does not know the result of the inner test steps
rescue Result::Raisable => exception
  exception.with_duration(@timer.duration)
rescue Exception => exception
  failed(exception)
end
```

So if it does not know the result of the inner test steps, then it definitely won't know of any exceptions ocurring in the rest of said steps.

P.S.  I have the same question...